# Webpages/Webmatrix - Defining a variable to hold the dynamic type returned from a db.Query

Tags: webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

How to declare a variable to hold the results of a db.query.

I'm using Webpages and Webmatrix to build some small apps.

As part of the authentication process I have to perform slightly different queries on the database depending on who is logged in.

```
var db = Database.Open("DBName");
var mySQL = "";

// WHAT LEVEL IS THE USER
if (PageData["editorLevel"] < 11){
    //set the sql
    //perform the db.Query
}else if (PageData["editorLevel"]<51){
    //set the sql
    //perform the db.Query      
}else if (PageData["editorLevel"] < 101){
    //set the sql   
    //perform the db.Query  
}
```

The db.Query will contain differing parameters so has to be executed within the if else block.

If I do it like so;

```
var myResults = db.Query(mySQL, parameter list)
```

then myResults will not be available in the rest of the page, so I need to define myResults first. I have tried all sorts of variations of Type myResults and var myResults but gettign no where.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Database helper Query method returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, so this could be your code:

```
var db = Database.Open("DBName");
var mySQL = "";
IEnumerable<dynamic> myResults = null;

// WHAT LEVEL IS THE USER
if (PageData["editorLevel"] < 11){
    //set the sql
    myResults = db.Query(mySQL, parameter list);
}
```